# How to compare md5 hash values on a condition on shell script?

Tags: shell

Question below the code.

```
#!/bin/sh

check() {   
    dir="$1"
    chsum1=`find ~/folder -type f -exec cat {} \; | md5` 
    chsum2=$chsum1

    for (( ; 0x$chsum1 == 0x$chsum2;  ))
    do
        echo "hello"
        sleep 10
        chsum2=`find ~/folder -type f -exec cat {} \; | md5`
    done

echo "hello"
#eval $2
}

check $*
```

The goal is: Make the code works. What it does? Applies md5 to a folder, then compare the md5 values. It maintains a loop until the value is different (that means something on the folder happened), thus after 10 secs when the md5 calculates the hash it should be different, then the code ends.

**Two Questions**.

1. Notice that there is a commented while there. If you uncomment the while and comment the for, you will notice the code stops working. Why? I tried different combinations for trying to make it work. I enclosed with quotes, used -eq, =, ==, etc. None worked. How could I make it work with a whole?
2. The way the code it is now, if it is run then what I get as output is:

> ((: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e == 97329acaae00bdf66e30ac53b49e1036: value too great for base (error token is "97329acaae00bdf66e30ac53b49e1036")

```
Thus, how can I fix this is the second question and why this is happening.
```

Thank you!

Comment: The link to pastebin is broken. Please paste the code into your question rather than posting it on another site.

Comment: I tried posting but I had trouble formatting the question here. I apologize for that.

Comment: I have copied the code in from pastebin, the edit needs to be accepted.  Basically, just paste the code, select it and hit the `{}` button above the text box to format it is as code.

Comment: I edited the question myself learning from editing yours. Although I was struggling to add 4 spaces to every line. I guess it looks okay now. At least the person who stumbles on it won't run on the chance that the code is not available. Thank you for letting me know about the {} too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having with the (updated) posted code is that you are using a `for` loop when a `while` loop works.

The following code works for me.  I simply changed the `for` loop to a `while` loop.

```
#!/bin/sh

check() {
        dir="$1"
        chsum1=`find ~/NASAtest -type f -exec cat {} \; | md5`
        chsum2=$chsum1

        while [ $chsum1 == $chsum2 ]
        do
                echo "hello"
                sleep 10
                chsum2=`find ~/NASAtest -type f -exec cat {} \; | md5`
        done

        echo "hello"
        #eval $2
}

check $*
```

The reason the while loop wasn't working is because you were missing spaces between the square brackets and the expression.

Comment: Hi I am sorry my question description was misleading. I updated it, would you mind editing your answer? I apologize for that.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking then.  Perhaps you should rewrite the question to make it clearer rather than simply adding a link to some code.

Comment: I did before posting the comment check it above! The link to the code is available already on paste bin!

Comment: I realise you updated your question.  You have simply added a link to some code and it is not clear what your problem is.  You asked a question about `while` loops and when we answer your question you say that isn't the problem and post a link to some source code that doesn't explain the question you actually want answered.  It would also be better if the code was posted on SO not pastebin.

Comment: I've downloaded your code and run it to try and work out what you want to do.  I've now fixed it and updated my answer to, hopefully, answer your question (assuming you don't change the question again).

Comment: Thank you so much for also adding the reasoning of why. Didn't notice that the spaces between the brackets were significant too. I up voted and accepted the answer. Sorry about the confusion. Too bad the question was down voted before I had time to fix (which was within 23 mins) but whatever :)

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the confusion about the format or type of variable you are comparing (value too great for base) by putting a Z in front of the value and comparing as strings.

```
# read or operation to define $file1 & $file2 here ...
  val1=`md5sum ${file1} | awk '{print $1}'`
  val2=`md5sum ${file2} | awk '{print $1}'`
  tmpval="Z${val1}" ; val1="${tmpval}"
  tmpval="Z${val2}" ; val2="${tmpval}"
  if [[ "$val1" -eq "$val2" ]] ; then
    # files are the same, do operation here ..
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> while [$chsum1 == $chsum2] do perform some stuff end

This needs to look like this (newlines included)

```
while [ $chsum1 == $chsum2 ]
do
 (perform some stuff)
done
```

Note the spaces around the square brackets and the `do`/`done` block instead of `end`.

Comment: Hi I am sorry my question description was misleading. I updated it, would you mind editing your answer? I apologize for that.

Comment: The problem with your while loop is you need spaces between your square brackets and the actual test.

Comment: I removed the code from the question because it is being misleading, the code on the question is the one on the link, sorry about that.

Comment: This is the while loop from your pastebin linke: `while [$chsum1 == $chsum2]`, this is the while loop from my post: `while [ $chsum1 == $chsum2 ]` there is spaces between the **$chsum1 == $chsum2** and the square brackets, otherwise sh gives you an error.

Comment: Although the answer was mislead by my question, it helped me realizing a most likely future mistake. Thank you for your time on answering it!